# SAS: How can I pad a character variable with zeroes while reading in from csv

Tags: sas

Most of my data is read in in a fixed width format, such as fixedwidth.txt:

```
00012000ABC
0044500DEFG
345340000HI
00234000JKL
06453MNOPQR
```

Where the first 5 characters are colA and the next six are colB. The code to read this in looks something like:

```
infile "&path.fixedwidth.txt" lrecl = 397 missover;
input   colA    $5.
        colB    $6.
;
label  colA  = 'column A  '
       colB  = 'column B  '
;
run;
```

However some of my data is coming from elsewhere and is formatted as a csv without the leading zeroes, i.e. example.csv:

```
colA,colB
12,ABC
445,DEFG
34534,HI
234,JKL
6453,MNOPQR
```

As the csv data is being added to the existing data read in from the fixed width file, I want to match the formatting exactly.

The code I've got so far for reading in example.csv is:

```
data work.example;
    %let _EFIERR_ = 0; /* set the ERROR detection macro variable */
    infile "&path./example.csv" delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;
    informat colA $5.;
    informat colB $6.;
    format colA z5.; *;
    format colB z6.; *;
    input
    colA $
    colB $
    ;
    if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1);  /* set ERROR detection macro variable */
run;
```

But the formats z5. & z6. only work on columns formatted as numeric so this isn't working and gives this output:

```
ColA     colB
12       ABC
445      DEFG
34534    HI
234      JKL
6453     MNOPQR
```

When I want:

```
ColA     colB
00012    000ABC
00445    00DEFG
34534    0000HI
00234    000JKL
06453    MNOPQR
```

With both columns formatted as characters.

Ideally I'd like to find a way to get the output I need using only formats & informats to keep the code easy to follow (I have a lot of columns to keep track of!).

Grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cats` to force the csv columns to character, without knowing what types the csv import determined they were.  Right justify the resultant to the expected or needed variable length and translate the filled in spaces to zeroes.

For example

```
data have;
  length a 8 b $7; * dang csv data, someone entered 7 chars for colB;

  a = 12;     b = "MNQ";     output;
  a = 123456; b = "ABCDEFG"; output;
run;

data want;
  set have (rename=(a=csvA b=csvB));

  length a $5 b $6;

  * may transfer, truncate or convert, based on length and type of csv variables;
  * substr used to prevent blank results when cats (number) is too long;
  * instead, the number will be truncated;
  a = substr(cats(csvA),1); 
  b = substr(cats(csvB),1);

  a = translate(right(a),'0',' ');
  b = translate(right(b),'0',' ');
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. To further complicate my example, is there a way to ensure zeros only replace spaces to the left of the character string? I.e. I'd want "A B C" to appear as "0A B C", not "0A0B0C".

Answer (score 0):

SUBSTR on the left.

```
data test;
   infile cards firstobs=2 dsd;
   length cola $5 colb $6;
   cola = '00000';
   colb = '000000';
   input (a b)($);
   substr(cola,vlength(cola)-length(a)+1)=a;
   substr(colb,vlength(colb)-length(b)+1)=b;
   cards;
colA,colB
12,ABC
445,DEFG
34534,HI
234,JKL
6453,MNOPQR
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how your code works. Please could you explain more detail?

Comment: SUBSTR on the LEFT of = allows you insert a value starting at a column eg. 5-2+1. So instead of changing characters to 0 it is inserting into field of zeros.  VLENGTH is function that return the defined length of a variable 5 or 6 in this case.  LENGTH measures the length of a character string.